# Unable to see scheduled job in Databricks workflow

Tags: azure-devops, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-pipelines-yaml, databricks-workflows

I am using service principal(PAT token) authentication to authenticate Databricks and schedule a Databricks Notebook.

```
trigger:
- development

pool: SharedAKS

jobs:
- job: AzureCLI
  steps:
  - checkout: self
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
      addSpnToEnvironment: true
      scriptType: 'pscore'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |
        #databrick cli
        # install databrick-cli
        $rg= "
        $storageAccountName=""
        $resourceGroup=$(az group list --query "[?contains(name, '$(rg)')].name | [0]" --output tsv)
        $accountKey=$(az storage account keys list --resource-group $rg --account-name $storageAccountName --query "[0].value" --output tsv)
        $env:STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY = $accountKey

        
        echo "Storage Account Key: $accountKey"
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel databricks-cli
        
        $wsId=(az resource show --resource-type Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces -g $(rg) -n $(databricksName) --query id -o tsv)
        $workspaceUrl=(az resource show --resource-type Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces -g $(rg) -n $(databricksName) --query properties.workspaceUrl --output tsv)

        $workspaceUrlPost='https://'
        $workspaceUrlPost+=$workspaceUrl
        $workspaceUrlPost+='/api/2.0/token/create'
        echo "Https Url with Post: $workspaceUrlPost"

        $workspaceUrlHttps='https://'
        $workspaceUrlHttps+=$workspaceUrl
        $workspaceUrlHttps+='/'
        echo "Https Url : $workspaceUrlHttps"

        # token response for the Azure Databricks app
        $token=(az account get-access-token --resource $(AZURE_DATABRICKS_APP_ID) --query "accessToken" --output tsv)
        echo "Token retrieved: $token"

        # Get a token for the Azure management API
        $azToken=(az account get-access-token --resource https://management.core.windows.net/ --query "accessToken" --output tsv)

        # Create PAT token valid for approximately 10 minutes (600 seconds). Note the quota limit of 600 tokens.
        $pat_token_response=(curl --insecure -X POST ${workspaceUrlPost} `
          -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" `
          -H "X-Databricks-Azure-SP-Management-Token:$azToken" `
          -H "X-Databricks-Azure-Workspace-Resource-Id:$wsId" `
          -d '{"lifetime_seconds": 6000,"comment": "this is an example token"}')
        
        echo "Token retriev: $token" 
        echo "DATABRICKS_TKN: $pat_token_response"
          
        # Print PAT token
        $dapiToken=($pat_token_response | ConvertFrom-Json).token_value
        #dapiToken=$(echo $pat_token_response | jq -r .token_value)
        echo "DATABRICKS_TOKEN: $dapiToken"
        $DATABRICKSTKN = $dapiToken
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DATABRICKSTKN]$DATABRICKSTKN"

  - script: |
      echo "$(DATABRICKSTKN)"
      echo "Starting Databricks notebook upload..."
      # Install Databricks CLI
      pip install databricks-cli
      echo "DATABRICKS_TOKEN: $(DATABRICKSTKN)"

      # Authenticate with Databricks using the PAT
      echo "Authenticating with Databricks..."
      echo "DATABRICKS_TOKEN: $dapiToken"
      databricks configure --token <<EOF
      https://adb-82410274.14.azuredatabricks.net
      $(DATABRICKSTKN)
      EOF
      # Specify the full paths to the source files
      common_function_path=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/notebook'
      
      # Specify the full target paths in Databricks
      common_function_target_path="/Users/user/notebook'
      

      # Upload notebooks to Databricks workspace
      echo "Uploading notebooks to Databricks..."
      databricks workspace import --language sql --overwrite "$common_function_path" "$common_function_target_path"
      
      echo "Notebooks uploaded successfully."

      echo "Flex_DDLs.sql notebook executed successfully."
    displayName: 'Upload Databricks Notebooks Job'
  
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Schedule Databricks Notebook'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: | 
        databricksUrl='https://adb-824194.14.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0'
        notebookPath='/Users/user/notebook'
        
        
        jobName='ScheduledJobName1'
        

        requestUri="$databricksUrl/jobs/create"
        
        

        body='{
          "name": "'$jobName'",
          "new_cluster": {
            "spark_version": "7.3.x-scala2.12",
            "node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2",
            "num_workers": 0
          },
          "notebook_task": {
            "notebook_path": "'$notebookPath'"
          },
          "schedule": {
              "quartz_cron_expression": "45 10 * * * ?",
              "timezone_id": "Canada/Eastern"
          }
        }'

        

        # Make the API request
        curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $(DATABRICKSTKN)" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$body" "$requestUri"
```

Below is the log for the scheduling part.

```
Starting: Schedule Databricks Notebook
==============================================================================
Task         : Bash
Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
Version      : 3.229.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/3d882ebd-1553-46f0-b2a2-4f29ff0.sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   401  100    26  100   375     54    791 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   845
{"job_id":789888762}  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   365  100    27  100   338     69    870 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   940
Finishing: Schedule Databricks Notebook
```

I can see the job_id generated in the logs, but I am unable to see the job in the Databricks.
Do I need any other access to see the jobs in databricks when authenticated with service principal(PAT token).

Thanks

Comment: How are you checking the job in Databricks (e.g. UI, REST API)? Can you try directly opening the job UI via its URL https://adb-<workspace id>.<random number>.azuredatabricks.net/?o=<workspace id>#job/789888762?

Comment: I m checking from UI and I have tried via the URL you suggested,it says job not found.

Comment: @Vin, did you check the databricks UI -> workflows-> jobs page? If the job doesn't exist, since the only variable in your Schedule bash task is `$(DATABRICKSTKN)`, to narrow down the issue, try to generate the databricks token from UI,  change the variable name in devops yaml(eg:`NewDATABRICKSTKN` ), then directly define its value in pipeline, will the job be created successfully then?

Comment: Once I was given contributor access, I was able to see the job in Databricks workflow.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are submitting job as a service principal, but attempting to view it as a user. You will only see the job if you are an admin (apparently you're not) or the job has an explicit ACL allowing you to see it.

Check [Jobs API docs](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/jobs/create) and add following to the payload:

```
access_control_list=[
  {"user_name": "you@example.com", "permission_level": "CAN_MANAGE_RUN"}
]
```